# Annotating plot bar from values of other a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a bar plot with matplotlib in which x values are in one column and the percentages of these values are in a separate column.

```
Gender Gain/Loss Final corrected classification  Values    percent  
0       F         G                         Benign    5619  11.658886   
1       F         G                  Likely Benign    7288  15.121901   
2       F         G              Likely Pathogenic     324   0.672269
```

To carry out out my plot I have been working with the code I show below but I am not able to annotate the values of the percentage column next to the bars

```
# Figure Size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(16, 9))


# Horizontal Bar Plot
ax.barh(df1['Final corrected classification'], df1['Values'])

# Remove axes splines
for s in ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']:
    ax.spines[s].set_visible(False)
    
# Remove x, y Ticks
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')

# Add padding between axes and labels
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad = 5)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(pad = 10)

# Add x, y gridlines
ax.grid(b = True, color ='grey',
        linestyle ='-.', linewidth = 0.5,
        alpha = 0.2)
 
# Show top values 
ax.invert_yaxis()

# Add annotation to bars
for p, percentage in zip(ax.patches, df1['percent']):
        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() + 0.1
        y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()/2
        ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y))
    
# Add Plot Title
ax.set_title('Number of variants',
             loc ='left', )
 
# Add Text watermark
fig.text(0.9, 0.15, 'STP', fontsize = 12,
         color ='grey', ha ='right', va ='bottom',
         alpha = 0.7)
 
# Show Plot
plt.show()
```

I have been getting different error, so far I got this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-365-151b04ec814c> in <module>
     29 
     30 for p in ax.patches:
---> 31         percentage = s["percent"].astype(int)
     32         x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() + 0.02
     33         y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()/2

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: You need less confusing variable names. Here `s` is used both as name for a dataframe as well as for a spine.

Comment: Apart from the mistaken variable name, you also need to loop through the percentage column. As in `for p, percentage in zip(ax.patches, s['percent']):`

Comment: I have fixed the variable issue and I have added the code provide by JohanC and it seems that work. The only thing is that the value annotated is very close to the bar, how can I more then a bit to the right?

Comment: You can add a space before the string. For example `ax.annotate(' '+str(percentage), ...)`